# Using Props in stateful and Stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to understand **why can't we use `this.props` in functional stateless component in react**.

For example, I was studying HOC where we get props like this

```
 const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
   console.log("this is wrapped component" + WrappedComponent)

return (props) => (
        <div className={className}>
           <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

Now, Since this a functional component so if we do something like

```
 <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
```

it won't work, So my question is why can't we use this.props in functional component.

Ps: `export default withClass( App, classes.App );`
where App is `class App extends PureComponent {` (in case someone is wondering about our arguments.

Comment: Google has your back: https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/react-how-to-access-props-in-a-functional-component-6bd4200b9e0b

Comment: Because `this` equals the global object in a function.

Comment: @Dan could please explain your comment in details?

Comment: @jmargolisvt It says **this”. Since it’s not a class you don’t have to reference the component itself.** . I know that, in-fact I mentioned the same in my question. I am curious about why not us `this.props` in stateless. (this keyword have always confused me in javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional component has no `this` as it is only a function. Function in JavaScript has no `this`, until function isn't a method of any object, or isn't a constructor function used by `new` keyword. Also what is important to mention, arrow function, so exactly what your HOC is, has no possibility to be bonded to specific context, as it is possible only for normal functions, we can say standard functions.

`This` keyword exists everywhere, in global scope it is just the `window` object, but only inside objects it represents the object instance, although we can bind custom context(this) to the standard function by using .bind or .call methods, but it is different subject.

Going back to React, if you create a class component you will have `this`, and `this.props` will work as class component is transformed into object by `new` keyword, and all its methods are bounded with `this` as a reference to the object.

**Summary** - functional components are pure functions which have props passed as function arguments and which have no own `this` object.

Some additional resources to read about that:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Very good article about context and scope:

- http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: Great Answer. 
I am unable to understand this line in your answer **this.props will work as class component is transformed into object by new keyword**

Comment: Class is only syntax sugar over object definition. So React Component will be created by new keyword like for example new SmthComponent and in that time every method in it will have bounded this.

Comment: Can you please explain your above comment in a stretch with example?

Answer (score 1):

@iRohitBhatia, your question is one that requires a journey into JavaScript basics because `this` is not actually a `Reactjs` concept but rather a JavaScript keyword. And here is a [good resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS), but i'll give a brief here.

> Before the ES6 standard, JavaScript largely used **Prototype-based programming** which is a style of object-oriented programming (OOP) in which classes are not directly defined, but instead derived by adding properties and methods to an instance of another class. ([See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Prototype-based_programming)).

So, in basic JavaScript, there two ways to create Object instances:
[Try this in Codepen](https://codepen.io/mwamitovi/pen/mddJXwo)

> 1. Using normal functions **(In React, think: functional/Stateless components)**

```
function createSchool(name, type) {
  const p = {};
  p.name = name;
  p.type = type;
  p.description = function(){
    alert('Hello, ' + p.name + ' is a ' + p.type + '.')
  };
  return p;
}

// create
const makerere = createSchool('Makerere', 'University');
const kitovu = createSchool("St. Henry's", 'college')
```

> 2. Using a constructor functions **(In React, think: class/stateful components)**

```
function School(name, type){
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.description = function(){
    alert('Hello, ' + this.name + ' is a ' + this.type + '.')
  }
}

// create
const makerere = new School('Makerere', 'university');
const kitovu = new School("St. Henry's", 'college');
```

> **Why `this` ?**

Using the constructor, we have two new objects each stored under a different namespace - that's why we call `makerere` or `kitovu` first so as to access the attributes. However, the two objects have the same attributes i.e. properties (`name` & `type` ) and method (`description`).

Despite that situation, each object uses the property values we assigned it at instantiation (create). The keyword `this` enables each object/class to use it's own values and not other unintended values.

So, in `Reactjs`, `this.props` enables each `class component` to strictly utilize it's own property values despite all classes inheriting from `React.Component`. While for `functional components`, `props` is implicitly unique to that component since they never share any parent.